# Google Maps API V3 Returns 610,0,0,0

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using Google Maps API V3 on my vb.net 2010 application.I tested `http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=csv&key=MYAPIKEY&q= 46 long street, kempton park` directly on the web browser and I get  `610,0,0,0` error. the whole point of my appllication is to get gps coordinates from the address and also get address from given gps coordinates. i tried generating a new browser key but is still not working. Thanks in advance. Please refer to the code below:

Can someone please advise why is Google Maps API returning this `610,0,0,0` error

```
Public Function GetLatLon(ByVal addr As String) As LatLon
    Dim url As String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=csv&key=MYAPIKEY" & addr
    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim buffer(2048) As Byte
        Dim count As Integer = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        While count > 0
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, count)
            count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End While
        responseStream.Close()
        ms.Close()
        Dim responseBytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
        Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim coords As String = encoding.GetString(responseBytes)
        Dim parts() As String = coords.Split(",")
        Return New LatLon(Convert.ToDouble(parts(2)), Convert.ToDouble(parts(3)))
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: **NEVER** share API keys in public. They are meant to stay private as an identification token. It's just like writing your email password on a T-shirt and walking in the crowd ;)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need take a look of HTML source code 
but here...
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=terracina,via+roma+100&sensor=false

i userd with my address

take a look
it is a google service, and you can get the XML's location

cheers

Comment: Thanks alot, it works perfectly returning result in an xml format. how do i read the xml file from a texbox and also chose which data to display? thanks in advance